# Declaring enums inside anonymous class

Tags: java, enums

Can we declare enums inside anonymous class?

I wrote one sample program surprisingly an empty enum without any enum constant inside anonymous class compiles but enum with enum constant doesn't.

Below program gives error message

> Main.java:16: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
>               obj.no(new a() { enum e{j} });

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class a {}
class Ideone
{
    public void no(a arg) {;} ;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        Ideone obj = new Ideone();
        obj.no(new a() { enum e{j,k;} });


    }
}
```

Program compiles if I remove enum constant j and k.

I don't understand rational behind this behavior. Since enum class are implicitly static they shouldn't be allowed inside anonymous or local classes but here it is allowing only empty enum classes.

Comment: Note that the Eclipse compiler doesn't allow the enum, even when empty. It says _The member enum e can only be defined inside a top-level class or interface or in a static context_

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have an enum type inside an anonymous class.

This is because anonymous classes are inner classes ([JLS 15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)):

> An anonymous class is always an inner class (§8.1.3)

and enum types can't be declared inside an inner class ([JLS 8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9)):

> A nested enum type is implicitly `static`. It is permitted for the declaration of a nested enum type to redundantly specify the `static` modifier.
>
> This implies that it is **impossible to declare an enum type in the body of an inner class** (§8.1.3), because an inner class cannot have `static` members except for constant variables.

---

Eclipse (tested with Mars 4.5.1) gives a compilation error for both cases (enum with and without a constant in an anonymous class) but it seems `javac` (tested with 1.8.0_51) only gives a compilation error for the case when the enum has a constant and compiles fine when the enum is empty; so it looks like there is a bug in `javac`.

Comment: So I suppose this is a bug in `javac`. Contrary to the Eclipse compiler, It does allow an `enum` without constants in that context. And its only complaint is about the constants.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Hmm I only tested with Eclipse and not with `javac` but yes, it looks like javac (at least 8) can compile this. Weird.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I can't find any bugs relating to this however.